# Functional Javascript algorithm not returning the expected result from a filter

Tags: javascript

I am practicing using map(), filter(), and concatAll()in Javascript.  I am expecting the code below to return the following:

```
[{
   "id": 70111470,
   "title": "Die Hard",
   "boxart":"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard150.jpg" 
}]
```

It is not pulling in the URL from the boxart and I am not sure why. I get the following output when I run my code:

```
[{"id": 70111470,"title": "Die Hard"}]
```

```
function() {
    var movieLists = [
        {
            name: "Instant Queue",
            videos : [
                {
                    "id": 70111470,
                    "title": "Die Hard",
                    "boxarts": [
                        { width: 150, height:200, url:"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard150.jpg" },
                        { width: 200, height:200, url:"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard200.jpg" }
                    ],
                    "url": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
                    "rating": 4.0,
                    "bookmark": []
                }
             ]
          }
        ];

    getBoxart = function(boxart){
        return boxart.width==150;
    };

    getVideoData = function(video){return {id: video.id, 
                                        title: video.title, 
                                       boxart: video.boxarts.filter(getBoxart).url}
    };

    getVideos = function(movie){return movie.videos.map(getVideoData)}

    return movieLists.map(getVideos).concatAll();
}
```

Comment: Where is `concatAll` coming from?

Comment: Without `concatAll` I get an extra Array: `[ [ { id: 70111470,
      title: 'Die Hard',
      boxart: 'http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard150.jpg' },
    { id: 654356453,
      title: 'Bad Boys',
      boxart: 'http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/BadBoys150.jpg' } ],
  [ { id: 65432445,
      title: 'The Chamber',
      boxart: 'http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/TheChamber150.jpg' },
    { id: 675465,
      title: 'Fracture',
      boxart: 'http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture150.jpg' } ] ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue is this line: `video.boxarts.filter(getBoxart).url`

filter is returning an array of boxarts (which does not have a url property)

you either need to map after filter to return an array of urls, or just grab the first one

Comment: I ended up using a map, as you suggested. `video.boxarts.         filter(getBoxart).map(function(bA){return bA.url;}).toString()`

Answer (score 0):

That's because

```
video.boxarts.filter(getBoxart)
```

returns an array (if that's the native implementation of `filter`, but probably for any other implementation as well), and then doing

```
video.boxarts.filter(getBoxart).url
```

returns `undefined` since arrays don't have a `url` property...

You probably need to do:

```
video.boxarts.filter(getBoxart)[0].url
```